# Why am I not getting back JSON content?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I am trying to get an object from my database using Spring REST API. The problem is that I am not receiving the content correctly.

My log output:

```
/hello
Hibernate: select this_.id as id0_0_, this_.countryCode as countryC2_0_0_ from Country this_ where this_.countryCode=?
Found: at
```

And the controller I use:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mahlzeit.datamodel.HibernateTest;
import com.mahlzeit.datamodel.address.Country;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")//, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Country hello(ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println("/hello");

        HibernateTest hbt = new HibernateTest();

        Session session = hbt.sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Country.class);
        cr.add(Restrictions.eq("countryCode", "at"));

        List<Country> queryAustria = cr.list();

        if (queryAustria.isEmpty() == true) {
            System.err.println("at not found");
            return null;
        }

        Country austria = null;
        for (Iterator<Country> iterator = queryAustria.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            Country country = (Country) iterator.next();
            if (country.getCountryCode().equals("at")) {
                austria = country;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Found: "+ austria.getCountryCode());

        return austria;
    }
}
```

So, I am getting back my desired object from Hibernate but what I am actually getting back is

> `HTTP Status 404`

This is **Country.java**:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2060021861139912774L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(length=2,unique=true)
    private String countryCode;

    // Setter & Getter ..
}
```

Config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mahlzeit.server.mobile" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Post the *entire* controller class.

Comment: @chrylis Ah sorry I think you missed something like the `@RestController` annotation. I updated my question but except from this annotation this is the whole controller.

Comment: @StefanFalk, are you getting any errors in server logs?

Comment: @Chaitanya No. The server starts without errors. After that I receive only my own output as stated in my question. I don't really know how I can debug this issue here.

Comment: @StefanFalk, show your spring configuration file

Comment: Turn up logging for `org.springframework.web` to `DEBUG`.

Comment: @chrylis How would I do that? I tried [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) and put that logback.xml file to `WEB-INF` but it doesn't work

Comment: @Chaitanya I think I got logging on but I receive only messages from Hibernate an not from Spring. What is the Spring configuration file? Sorry I'm learning REST; Hibernate; Spring etc. all at once here ..

Comment: @StefanFalk, Ok then follow some tutorial, there are so many examples available in internet. Practice the examples for `@RestController` then you will understand where the issue is with your code.

Comment: @Chaitanya This is what I am doing ^^ I have added the beans definition. Did you mean that?

Comment: @Chaitanya I don't understand the close-votes? I was basically following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I don't understand what is wrong with my question?

Comment: @StefanFalk, Given answer, please check and see if that fixes the issue. I think the close votes are because this is a basic question and you will find so many examples in internet.

Comment: @StefanFalk Absolutely be careful about mixing tutorials. I recommend starting with Spring Boot if you're doing any new work, as it generally will automatically set all of this stuff up for you.

Comment: @chrylis Already did that mistake when learning the Android stuff - I should have known better already :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `InternalResourceViewResolver` then Spring will try to resolve the `View` based on `view name` that you are passing. So it will look for the file `/WEB-INF/austria.jsp` assuming the controller is returning the value as "austria". So that is the reason you are getting `404` error.

So to fix the issue, add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in Spring configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mahlzeit.server.mobile" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Also you need to have the JSON related Jars in your classpath -- `WEB-INF/lib` folder:

**[jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13) & [jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13)**

Comment: Okay I should stop mixing up tutorials because this holds me insanely back. I got the config file from a tutorial where the tutorial from the Spring website does not mention one Usinng `<mvc:annotation-driven />` instead of `<bean>...</bean>` solved the issue! Thanks! Got the Jackson (v2.5.3) stuff imported via Maven.

Comment: @StefanFalk, my bad, it is not required to remove the `InternalResourceViewResolver` in Spring configuration file. You just need to add the `mvc` tag and then put the Jar files in class path. Updated the answer with correct information now.